# Why does this pygtk TextView refuse to wrap?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have a textview inside a scrolledwindow that refuses to wrap to words/chars/wordschars no matter how I set the wrap mode. It simply extends the size of itself and its containers as it pleases. Here's an example:

```
import gtk

window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
window.set_default_size(256,256)
scroll = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
scroll.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_NEVER, gtk.POLICY_ALWAYS)
view = gtk.TextView()
view.set_wrap_mode(gtk.WRAP_CHAR)
scroll.add(view)
window.add(scroll)
window.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

How can I make it wrap? If it matters, I need the parent window to be resizeable by the user, just not the text.

Comment: Maybe you meant to use WRAP_WORD instead of WRAP_CHAR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the size request on the `TextView`'s container (which is `scroll` in your example), not the `Window` or the `TextView` itself.

Try the following:

```
import gtk

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    scroll = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    scroll.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_NEVER, gtk.POLICY_ALWAYS)
    view = gtk.TextView()
    view.set_wrap_mode(gtk.WRAP_CHAR)
    scroll.set_size_request(256, 256)
    scroll.add(view)
    window.add(scroll)
    window.show_all()
    gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code and word wrapping seems to be working fine. What are you running it on? I'm using PyGTK 2.22 on Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: I tested the example code and it works.. kind of. Try making the window larger after it starts wrapping, and then try making it smaller again. It's definitely somewhat broken.